# Redirecting old permalinks to new ones in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

After searching all around, i can find threads related to my question but not exactly what i want.
I have to change the permalink structure from **/category/postname** to **/postname/**. But when i change the structure, my old links are throwing 404 errors. I have around 10k posts on my site & I don't want to loose my traffic or affect SEO ranking.
So, for that (301 redirection), i tried everything that i found online. Like:

- I read somewhere Wordpress automatically handles redirection after changing permalinks. But couldn't see in my case.
- Setting up Redirection Plugin, tried updating permalinks after installing the plugin, manually inserted the redirections **/%category%/%post-name%** to **/%post-name%/**, but didn't work.
- Editing .htaccess file, used Yoast Permalink Helper to generate the code (  **RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ http://pristinekashmir.com/$2**  ) & inserted into the file. But this also didn't work, instead the code worked at backend/dashboard of WP. it throwed 404 pages on accessing wp-admin links, i think it was stripping the "category" in wp-admin.

Please help me in this issue. What is the proper code to be inserted in htaccess file or any plugin or anything by which i can make the 301 redirection work?

Things to be noted:

- I'm not so good at coding, this is my first site & I'm still in learning process :)
- I'm on latest version of Wordpress (4.6.1)
- Use W3 Total Cache, Yoas Seo Plugin
- I also tried the above methods after deactivating all the plugins, but nothing happened.

Thank You!

Comment: disable W3 Total Cache. and update a paramlinks

Comment: Tried that but didn't work.
Can you be more specific like how the redirection will work? Plugin? or Wordpress itself? Or do i have to add any code in .htaccess file?

Comment: please check answer

Answer (score 0):

- backup .htaccess file and delete it or rename.
- update your permalink structure to default ( ?p=ID ) so you ensure that .htaccess is the problem.
- After that, you could simply set "month and name" structure again, and see if it works.

Comment: After changing to default structure (?p=123), then "month and name". Old links (/category/postname/) started redirecting to "month and name" structure without any problem.
But after changing to (/postname/), it doesn't work.

Comment: did you removed htaccss??

Comment: I want it to redirect from ""/category/postname"" to ""/postname/""

Comment: disable redirect plugin if you are used any

Comment: Yes, deleted the .htaccess file & then updated the permalinks to default to create the .htaccess file again.

Comment: remove htaccess update with Post name  in paramlinks

Comment: can you please send me a url??

Comment: I can see other redirection are working like:
post-id  to  month-year
month-year  to  category/postname
postname  to  category/postname

But the only thing i want isn't working
category/postname  to  postname

Comment: Current structure: Sample link of a post  http://pristinekashmir.com/topics/life-science/under-50-smokers-face-8-fold-higher-heart-attack-risk-study

Comment: please check functions.php is there any custom code for redirection?

Comment: No, i haven't added any such code for redirection. But i have added a code once that can strip the tags from the feed. I don't think that should create any problem.

How can i show you my functions.php code so that you can check it yourself as already mentioned I'm not good at coding.

If i paste it here, it won't look good.

Comment: add_filter('get_the_tags', 'strip_tags_from_feeds');
function strip_tags_from_feeds($terms) {
    if (is_feed())
      return array();
    return $terms;
}

Comment: ok can you send me credential of admin at vasimmca007atgmail.com

Comment: The site is live right now & i don't want it to be in maintenance mode in peak traffic hours.

Comment: Please suggest some methods so that i can perform them later as the traffic remains low during night.

Comment: If its live then you need download and perform action in local